# Notable to changing workspace from source control explorer in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, source-control-explorer

I am using visual studio 2019 and install the latest update version 16.2.5 and I am using multiple workspaces for multiple solutions. I faced an issue that I am not able to change the workspace from source control explorer.

[image]

I should able to change the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that it is due to multiple screens. If I am using visual studio 2019 on my main screen then it is working fine. It is having the issue on add-on screen.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/725053/cant-change-workspace-via-source-control-explorer.html